# "sql like" alternatives for apache hive

Tags: java, jdbc, hadoop, distributed, hive

I am looking a solution for a *distributed database* that will support queries similar to sql.
To be more precise it should have a JDBC connector and same or similar to sql syntax.
From googling I found `HIVE` with hadoop.
What other alternatives do you know of?

Answer (score 2):

Cloudera [Impala](http://blog.cloudera.com/blog/2012/10/cloudera-impala-real-time-queries-in-apache-hadoop-for-real/) is a framework which supports SQL like queries and is compatible with HiveQL..

While Hive has been for some time and oriented for batch processing, Impala is new and is geared for real time processing.

Not exactly sure if JDBC works with Impala.

Comment: They're working on JDBC with Impala, and I believe the projected release for it is sometime Jan-Mar 2013.

Comment: A JDBC driver shipped with Impala 0.5: https://ccp.cloudera.com/display/IMPALA10BETADOC/Configuring+Impala+to+Work+with+JDBC

Answer (score 1):

The hive thrift server is something you might want to look at. Be aware of the pitfalls though.

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/HiveServer

Comment: which pitfalls do you mean?

Comment: It can only handle one client at a time. Take a look at the link I pasted. There is a rewrite in progress by the community, but I am not sure of its status. Also, zero security. Anyone can connect to the server and it will perform queries as the user the server is running as.